# Visual studio 2015 win 7 32. "cocos2d" is ambigious but still compiled and run

Tags: cocos2d-x

After follow this instruction, http://www.gamefromscratch.com/post/2014/09/29/Cocos2D-x-Tutorial-Series-Installation-Creating-a-Project-and-Hello-World.aspx

_Download and setup cocos

_Run cocos new -l cpp -p com.gamefromscratch.helloworld -d E:\4-Project\cocos\projec\helloworld helloworld

_Open visual studio solution inside proj.win32 folder.

I open cocos via visual studio on my windows 7 x64, and visual studio tell me that cocos2d namespace is ambigious. I tried to run the same project with same visual studio on windows 10, the problem disappeared. Althought project can still be run and debug perfectly fine, those red line still keep coming.
Here is my visual studio and config ( default of cocos)!

[image: Visual studio showing error]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You created the project from the console right ? Those lines of code are modified ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After serveral hour unsuccess. I finally installed c++ resharper and disable visual studio IDE. The problem finally gone!

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not wrong the cocos2d namespace is the "USING_NS_CC" macro and is in the HelloWorld .cpp file, you have a syntax error in the header file, to correct it:

```
class HelloWorld : public cocos2d::Layer
{
  ...
}
```

To create a cocos2d project and work on a desktop platform like Windows is very simple as long as you have at least the following:

- Visual Studio 2012 (for Windows)
- Python 2.7.5

After downloading [cocos2d-x](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/download), you should open the command line (CMD) and paste the following:

> python
>   "C:\Users\User\Downloads\folder-cocos2d-x\tools\cocos2d-console\bin\cocos.py"
>   new MyGame -d "C:\Users\User\Documents" -l cpp

Replacing a valid route will of course take a few minutes to create your new project

[Documentation](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/How_to_Start_A_New_Cocos2D-X_Game#For-Win32-Users)